# Alembic migration does not execute in pytest database setup fixture when called

Tags: python, pytest, fastapi, database-migration, alembic

## Summary

Hello, I'm setting up a pytest fixture that will run a migration against an in-memory SQLite database to set up for further testing. (This is a FastApi project by the way.) No matter what change the migration upgrade is called but appears to have no effect. I check to confirm that an expected table has been added and it isn't there. The Alembic folder is properly found and called. The alembic upgrade command is called. And nothing happens. No errors are thrown, I get no indication of any issues when executing the migration. I expect that I'm missing something simple/obvious but no idea what. Full GitHub source is available [here](https://github.com/cantis/CoinPurseThree/tree/feature/add_database)

### The Pytest File

```py
from alembic import command
from alembic.config import Config
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
import logging
from os import environ, path
import pytest
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, StaticPool, inspect
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

from src.main import app
from database.models import get_db
from alembic import op
import sqlalchemy as sa


LOG_PATH = path.join(path.dirname(path.abspath(__file__)), '../tests/test.log')
logging.basicConfig(
    format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
    filename=LOG_PATH,
    filemode='a',
    level=logging.DEBUG,
)
logging.debug('Test Initalize')

client = TestClient(app)

TEST_DATABASE_URL = 'sqlite:///:memory:'

engine = create_engine(
    TEST_DATABASE_URL,
    connect_args={
        'check_same_thread': False,
    },
    poolclass=StaticPool,
)
TestingSessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

# This method and the dependency_overide, overrides the get_db method in the main.py file
def override_get_db():
    """Override the database session for testing."""
    database = TestingSessionLocal()
    try:
        yield database
    finally:
        database.close()

app.dependency_overrides[get_db] = override_get_db


# Setup the database for testing
@pytest.fixture(scope='session', autouse=True)
def apply_migrations():
    """Setup the database for testing."""
    logging.debug('Applying migrations')
    engine = create_engine(TEST_DATABASE_URL)
    with engine.begin() as connection:
        alembic_cfg = Config('alembic.ini')
        alembic_cfg.attributes['configure_logger'] = True
        alembic_cfg.attributes['connection'] = connection
        alembic_cfg.set_main_option('script_location', './src/alembic')
        try:
            command.ensure_version(alembic_cfg)
            command.upgrade(alembic_cfg, 'head') # <- alembic upgrade here
            assert engine.dialect.has_table(engine, 'players') # <- error is found here, no table
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f'Exception during migration: {e}')
            raise e
        yield
        engine.dispose()

    def test_create_player(apply_migrations):
    # arrange
    data = {
        'playerName': 'test_player',
        'password': 'test_password',
        'email': 'test@noplace.com',
        'isAdmin': False,
    }

    # act
    # inspector = inspect(engine)
    # tables = inspector.get_table_names()

    response = client.post(
        '/players/',
        json=data,
    )

    # assert
    assert response.status_code == 201
    response_data = response.json()
    assert response_data['playerId'] == 1
    assert response_data['playerName'] == 'test_player'
    assert response_data['password'] == 'test_password'
    assert response_data['email'] == 'test@noplace.com'
    assert response_data['isAdmin'] is False
```

### The Migration

```py
"""initial migration

Revision ID: 264e0a95c5f8
Revises: 
Create Date: 2023-12-30 18:53:59.435418

"""
from typing import Sequence, Union

from alembic import op
import sqlalchemy as sa


# revision identifiers, used by Alembic.
revision: str = '264e0a95c5f8'
down_revision: Union[str, None] = None
branch_labels: Union[str, Sequence[str], None] = None
depends_on: Union[str, Sequence[str], None] = None


def upgrade() -> None:
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.create_table('characters',
    sa.Column('characterId', sa.Integer(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('characterName', sa.String(), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('playerId', sa.Integer(), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('isActive', sa.Boolean(), nullable=True),
    sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint('characterId')
    )
    op.create_table('players',
    sa.Column('playerId', sa.Integer(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('playerName', sa.String(), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('password', sa.String(), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('email', sa.String(), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('isAdmin', sa.Boolean(), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('isActive', sa.Boolean(), nullable=True),
    sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint('playerId')
    )
    op.create_table('transactions',
    sa.Column('transactionId', sa.Integer(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('characterId', sa.Integer(), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('amount', sa.Float(precision=2), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('description', sa.String(), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('transactionDate', sa.DateTime(), nullable=True),
    sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint('transactionId')
    )
    # ### end Alembic commands ###


def downgrade() -> None:
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.drop_table('transactions')
    op.drop_table('players')
    op.drop_table('characters')
    # ### end Alembic commands ###
```

I have tried changing the location I'm pointing at for alembic and get an error as expected. It finds the migrations. If I run the migration manually to create a SQLite db file on disk it does, and the table I need ('people') is confirmed in it. If I run the migration manually and then manually run a test using the FastApi Swagger it runs properly, this is limited to the pytest fixture. Most frustrating is that the error is silent silent.